# count '9's from 1 to n

Tags: python

Решаю задачу на codewars.com
Задача: count '9's from 1 to n
Моё решение:

```
def count_nines(n):
    list1 = str(list(range(1,n+1)))
    count = 0
    nine = ['9']
    for i in list1:
        if i in nine:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Ошибка: MemoryError если через сайт запускать, в моем IDE все работает как надо, правда медленно при больших числах
Еще из ограничений самой платформы codewars:

1. функция должна принимать только 1 аргумент
2. выполняться за время не более 12000 ms

Comment: Ну а теперь попробуйте в качестве n задать 1000000000 и посмотрите будет ли работать

Comment: @andreymal я попробовал, компьютеру поплохело....

Comment: Вообще тут наверное нужно придумать формулу, но мне лень, а если использовать перебор по всему набору чисел, то решение записывается в одну строку (но оно всё равно медленное) `count_nines = lambda n: sum(str(i).count('9') for i in range(1, n+1))`

Comment: @andreymal я новичок и решаю задачу как могу, но не могу понять, почему мой код требует такие трудоёмкие вычисления у компьютера?

Comment: @andreymal кстати, вот это выдает ошибку: `def count_nines(n):
    count_nines = lambda n: sum(str(i).count("9") for i in range(1,n+1))
    return count_nines`

Comment: Если переводить в строку не весь список, а каждое число по отдельности, то мемори эррор не случится. Хотя быстрее не станет.

Comment: Потому что вы делаете `str(list(range(1,n+1)))` и записываете все числа в одну большую строку. А теперь возьмите в руки калькулятор и посчитайте, сколько символов занимает такая строка? Подсказка: почти 9 миллиардов. Один символ занимает 4 байта. У вас есть 34 гигабайта оперативки?

Comment: @andreymal Но это была вынужденная мера, мне пришлось из цифры "9" сделать nine = ['9']  символ "9", а если это уже не цифра, то и str приписать к (list(range(1,n+1))

Comment: Список чисел без строки — даже хуже: одно число занимает 32 байта, указатель на объект 8 байт, итого такой список чисел будет занимать больше 37 гигабайт оперативки

Comment: @andreymal а все же, что там с вашим вариантом, почему выдает: **<function count_nines.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000296226EE9E0>**

Comment: Потому что вы пытаетесь возвращать функцию из функции непонятно зачем

Comment: @andreymal правила игры заставляют использовать функцию, что нужно из нее вернуть?

Comment: Ну перепиште без лямбды, в чём проблема-то `def count_nines(n): return sum(str(i).count('9') for i in range(1, n+1))`

Comment: @andreymal хм, тогда **Execution Timed Out**

Comment: Ну да, я говорил что оно медленное, нужно формулу придумывать (но мне лень)

Comment: Не надо там приписывать ни str, ни list. Откуда вообще такая вредная идея? Надо просто брать каждое число по отдельности и его проверять.

Comment: @Эникейщик не знаю почему, но такой код не работает(

Comment: Какой "такой"??

Comment: Скольк девяток в промежутке 1-9? 10-19? 100-199? 200-299? Если подумать для некоторых дипазаонов можно вывести формулы. Затем составить произвольное n из таких диапазонов.

Comment: @Эникейщик `def count_nines(n):
    list1 = range(1,n+1)
    count = 0
    nine = ['9']
    for i in list1:
        if i in nine:
            count = count + 1
    return count`

Comment: Конечно не работает. Ещё раз: список не нужен! Зачем вы опять его создаёте?

Comment: @Эникейщик так? `def count_nines(n):
    count = 0
    nine = ["9"]
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i in nine:
            count = count + 1
    return count`

Comment: Для `10_000_000` через `.count` в строке укладывается в 4 секунды. А если числа сильно больше, то только уже формулой считать тогда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*NB: Я везде ниже немного занижаю оценки, чтобы проще было объяснять.*

Исходное решение требует *O(n)* памяти. Сперва строится список чисел из *n* чисел. Затем строится строка в которой *O(n)* символов. Всё это может не поместится в память при больших *n*. Поправить можно сравнительно просто:

```
def count_nines(n):
    return sum(str(i).count('9') for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

Это код использует фиксированное количество памяти, но всё ещё работает за линейное время (то есть медленно), потому что перебирает все числа от единицы до *n*.

### Быстрое решение

Обозначим *f<sub>n</sub>* - число девяток в десятичных записях всех чисел *[0, n)*. Обратите внимание, что *n* исключено.

Обозначим *g<sub>n</sub>* - число девяток в десятичной записи числа *n*.

Как связаны *f<sub>n</sub>* и *f<sub>10n</sub>*?

*f<sub>10n</sub> = 10f<sub>n</sub> + n*.

Чтобы понять почему это так выпишем все числа *[0, 10n)* в таблицу. Вот её кусочек (последний разряд отделен пробелом только для читабельности):

> ```
> ...
> 987 0   # '987' входил в f_n один раз
> 987 1   # он же входит в f_10n десять раз
> 987 2   # таким образом первое слагаемое 10f_n
> 987 3   # перечисляет все девятки со второго разряда и выше
> 987 4
> 987 5
> 987 6
> 987 7
> 987 8
> 987 9   # девяток в первом разряде ровно n штук  
> ...     # это второе слагаемое
> ```

Усложним формулу. Появилась добавка *d*. Лишние числа добавляем в сумму в ручном режиме:

*f<sub>10n+d</sub> = 10f<sub>n</sub> + n + ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>d-1</sup> (g<sub>10n+i</sub>)*

Используя эту формулу можно решить задачу так:

```
def g(n):
    return str(n).count('9')


def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    d = n % 10
    m = n // 10
    return 10 * f(m) + m + sum(g(10 * m + i) for i in range(d))


def count_nines(n):
    return f(n + 1)
```

Время работы этой программы пропорционально количеству разрядов в числе *n*.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать:

```
def digit_count(digit, start, end):
    count = 0
    for number in range(start, end):
        while number:
            count += (number%10 == digit)
            number //= 10
    return count
```

Если можно использовать модули, то можно сделать так:

```
def digit_count(digit, start, end):
    @functools.lru_cache()
    def f(digit, number, first_call=False):
        if number==0 and first_call==False:
            return 0
        return (number%10==digit) + f(digit, number//10)
    count = 0
    for number in range(start, end):
        count += f(digit, number, first_call=True)
    return count
```

Comment: Должно работать медленнее чем оригинальная программа.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, некешированная фнк. действительно медленнее, однако проблема у автора не время, а память.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Обидно что задача красивая и решается почти за логарифм, а споры идут вокруг решений хуже чем за линию.

Comment: @n1tr0xs еще из ограничений самой платформы codewars : 1)функция должна принимать только 1 аргумент  2) выполняться за время не более 12000 ms

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можете объяснить что значит "решается почти за логарифм"?

Comment: Есть алгоритм, который решает задачу за время пропорциональное числу цифр в `n`. Число `10^100000` обрабатывается за 3 секунды.

Comment: @y3x3la, выпишите (в уме) в числа в столбец, выровняйте по последней цифре и сосчитайте количество девяток в последнем столбце (это можно сделать в одно арифметическое выражение), в предпоследнем и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
    x += str(i).count('9')
print(x)
```

Comment: Добавьте пару предложений чем ваше решение лучше. А то ответ уже в очереди на удаление.